# why string in Bundle is getting modified in Android?

Tags: android, string

I want to send a firebase token in a bundle to another activity. Firebase Token is 163 chars long but end up getting 165 chars with multiple mismatches.

Original:

```
cNAMo3kXRRmTl3WEAPDz1b:APA91bEjMeqAkcqy8RXifh_ZZFXBqjq6CvnkfqfbJ_8jgnjubHEFpHe8P2YKRDyOv98NhRbDoSlsei6VKh5abM9K-Z6mCavOdxOvyIC6ezCH_LqgM1mPD0NN0iEg5jI01ZSiPQl_O3yM
```

After retrieving from the bundle:

```
cNAMo3kXRRmTl3WEAPDz1b%3AAPA91bEjMeqAkcqy8RXifh_ZZFXBqjq6CvnkfqfbJ_8jgnjubHEFpHe8P2YKRDyOv98NhRbDoSlsei6VKh5abM9K-Z6mCavOdxOvyIC6ezCH_LqgM1mPD0NN0iEg5jI01ZSiPQl_O3yM
```

Now if you check you will see that at char no.22 is modified `: turns to %3`.
**So what can i possibly do to stop this behaviour?**

(sorry i am in doubt to categorize this question in which category except typical android tag. Any edits is welcome)

Comment: `:` is URL encoded as `%3A`. So `s = URLDecoder.decodeURL(s, "UTF-8")` probably. Left and right of the colon is URL-safe Base64 using _ and - instead of / and +,

Comment: ok, that could be a fix I guess but is this the actual behaviour of bundle in android? i mean why should the bundle even modify the string? then for getting the actual string do i have to write the suggest line in everywhere i receive the bundle?

Comment: Please do not consider my comment for patching something up. More Android experienced people should offer a suitable solution. (As the strings look like authentication keys, you might abbreviate them with ... - now that it is clear `:` was URL encoded to `%3A` resulting in 2 chars more. I saw a similar string in JSON, _not_ URL-encoded.)